# problem with react export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, token, react-router-dom

I was following a tutorial until I got this error. I know that this is caused by some changes on `react-router-dom`, but I have no idea of how to change this code to the new version, can you give me any suggestions?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const parseJwt = (token) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

class AuthVerify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    props.history.listen(() => {
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

      if (user) {
        const decodedJwt = parseJwt(user.accessToken);

        if (decodedJwt.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
          props.logOut();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(AuthVerify);
```

Comment: `react-router-dom@6` deprecated and removed the `withRouter` HOC. It also doesn't directly expose out the `history` object either, so you won't be able to call any `history.listen`. Is the purpose of this code to serve as a sort of route protection? Can you edit to show how it's used?

Comment: @DrewReese hi, i took the code from this tutorial 

https://www.bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/

do you think i should downgrade react-router-dom or should i modify the code? Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: That's entirely a decision only you or the team you work with on your project can make the determination for. IMO I'd vote for using RRDv6 over reverting back to v5 for any "real" project/app. Reverting back to v5 to match the tutorial would be the easiest solution in the case you are only doing this to learn and need to have a running project. In the least it will help you learn some core concepts with React, routing, authentication, etc. If you want to continue with v6 you can edit the post to include your [mcve] and we can suggest changes for RRDv6.